# How to change default filemanager in Linux

Tags: gnome, konqueror, file-management

How can I change the default file manager to Konqueror in Gnome-based distros? Currently it is Nautilus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I edited a script originally written for thunar to work for konqueror:

[My script](http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/961121/defaultkonqueror),
[Original script](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DefaultFileManager)

Download the script to your home folder and then make it executable:

```
chmod +x defaultkonqueror
```

Then run it to make konqueror the default file manager:

```
./defaultkonqueror
```

And run it again if you want nautilus to the default again.